# Tokens for Webform Component

Tags: 6, webforms

Is there a way to set up a Webform such that I can turn component field submissions into tokens for use in the submission email?

For example, I want to include "Message from [email address]" in the email subject line. The default options only allow for including only the component field in the email (subject: [email]), or only custom text.

Is there a way I can turn the component field submission into a token for use in the email? Looks like there's a module for turning webform items into tokens, but it's not for use within webform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Use `%value[key]`.